# How do I wrap an Ant task that calls javac with includeantruntime="true" in my Gradle build?

Tags: java, ant, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to wrap a 3rd party Ant build with Gradle.

Everything is working fine so far except that in one of the Ant targets javac is used with includeantruntime="true" and when run via Gradle it fails to compile because it doesn't have the Ant runtime in the classpath.

Note that javac calls with includeantruntime="false" work fine.

Does anyone know what I need to add to my Gradle build file to include the Ant runtime as a dependency?

Here is my current build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    junitAnt
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.5'
    }
}

dependencies {
    junitAnt 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    junitAnt('org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.5') {
        transitive = false
    }
    junitAnt('org.apache.ant:ant-junit4:1.9.5') {
        transitive = false
    }
}

ant.taskdef(name: 'junit', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask',
             classpath: configurations.junitAnt.asPath)

ant.importBuild ('build.xml')


task props << {
    ant.echoproperties(destfile:'dump-properties.txt', format:'text')
}
```

And this is the offending javac usage (note that JUnitLogFixFormatter does indeed need the Ant runtime in the classpath to compile):

```
<javac srcdir="${lib.dir}" destdir="${build-test.dir}" debug="true"
  includeantruntime="true" encoding="utf-8" target="1.6" source="1.6">
  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
  <classpath location="${junit.jar}"/>
  <include name="JUnitLogFixFormatter.java"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: As far as I understood you need ant runtime to run tests? If so, add ant dependency to scope `testRuntime`, it should be enough.

Comment: @Opal, no I need the runtime to build a utility class that is used by some tests. But in theory this is a problem for any javac target in a wrapped Ant build that declares includeantruntime="true"